# Is it possible to automate "npm publish" prompts?

Tags: npm, npm-publish

Running `npm publish` to push a package to NPM there are several prompts where you confirm package name, license, etc.

Is there an equivalent of `npm publish -y`? (i.e. in the way that `apt-get install <pkg> -y` will automatically just say 'yes' for all prompts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the command does not support that right now

Comment: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5002. It looks like yarn does support this.